# Vector and dual vector in Newman-Penrose formalism

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I am confused about the vector and dual vector in the tetrad formalism. Start from Schwarzschild metric

$$\mathrm{d} s^2=\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)dt^2 - \left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d} r^2-r^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+sin^2\theta \mathrm{d}\phi^2).$$
Change to the advanced Eddington-Finkelstein coordinate it becomes

$$\mathrm{d} s^{2}=\left (1-\frac{2m}{r} \right ) \mathrm{d} v^{2}-2 dv dr-r^{2}\left(\mathrm{d} \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi^{2}\right).$$
Then I could use it to construct the following null tetrad.

$\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{l}
\ell ^{a}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial r})^a, \\
n^{a}=-(\frac{\partial}{\partial v})^a-\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{2 m}{r}\right) (\frac{\partial}{\partial r})^a, \\
m^{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\left((\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})^a+\frac{i}{\sin \theta} (\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi})^a\right), \\
\bar{m}^{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\left((\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})^a-\frac{i}{\sin \theta} (\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi})^a\right).
\end{array}
\end{equation}$

The metric with respect to the tetrad is

$\begin{equation}
    g_{i j}=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}$

What would be the form of dual vectors with respect to $\{v,r,\theta,\phi\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did these equations come from? You have an index of the left hand sides of the equations but no on the right hand side... Such equations/definition are just plain wrong. What I think you should have written
$$\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{l}
\ell=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \\
n=-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{2 m}{r}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \\
m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{i}{\sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right), \\
\bar{m}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}-\frac{i}{\sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right).
\end{array}
\end{equation}$$
Now this perhaps does define some tetrad, if we further define the what are the coordinates (I'm going to assume $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3) = (r,v,\theta,\phi)$) and what is the metric. A general tensor $T$ can be written in a coordinate system as $T = T^a \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$, where we denote $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ as the (coordinate) basis.

From this it's obvious what you should have written as $l^a$ since
$$
l = \frac{\partial}{\partial r } = l^r \frac{ \partial}{\partial r }
$$
Thus your vector $l^\alpha = (1,0,0,0)$. Now if we want to lower these indices, we can, just as always do
$$
l_a = g_{a m} l^m = g_{a r}l^r
$$
Since $l^r$ is the only non-zero component.
For the process for other tetrad vector is practically the same.

Edit:
Now that we have the metric, we can finish our calculation of $l_a$.
Since the only non-zero metric term with $r$ is $g_{v r}$ the only non-zero term of $l_a$ will be $l_v$

$$
l_v = g_{vr}l^r = -1
$$
So now
$$
l_a = -1 \; dv_a
$$

Comment: I edit the question, It should be more clear now.

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: I think $g_{vr}$ should be one, beause the -2 is $g_{vr}+g_{rv}$. Actually, it still confused me. Why do we use metric in $\{v,r,\theta,\phi\}$ to lower the index, rather than using the metric of the tetrad to lower the index?

Comment: Sorry you are right about the factor.

Comment: Sorry I did't get to the answer. The question which metric to use to lower(raise) an index isn't easy to answer. Well actually it is: you can use any metric you so please. But for these vector I would suggest to use the given in the "coordinate basis" (that is **not** the one with zeros and ones). That is because for this metric we have something like $g^{ab} = -l^a n^b - n^a l^b + m^a \tilde{m}^b + \tilde{m}^a m^b$ so we would also like to have the equation $g_{ab} = -l_a n_b - n_a l_b + m_a \tilde{m}_b + \tilde{m}_a m_b$. Now it's obvious what metric to use when we compare the sides.

Comment: For more detailed answer please open a new question. Since I believe the question was posed rather differently in the original version.

Comment: I already figure out this problem. Using abstract index a, and b to represent the vector index. $l_{a}=g_{ab}l^b$, as $l^b=(\partial/\partial r)^b$, $l_{a}=g_{ar}l^r=g_{vr}(dv)_a$. Thank you!